# Wild Card DNS setup problems

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcard

this is my firast time with dedicated servers and im having problem setting up a wildcard sub-domain.

I previously tried

```
 * /-----/ 14400 /-----/ IN /-----/ A /-----/ (serverip)
```

waited 30 hours and nothing.

so i then tried

```
 * /-----/ 14400 /-----/ IN /-----/ CNAME /-----/ actvbiv.co.uk.
```

waited another 30 hours, nothing

Im now trying;

```
*.actvbiz.co.uk /-----/ 14400 /-----/ IN /-----/ CNAME /-----/ actvbiv.co.uk.
```

Am i doing this correctly?

using WHM.

Regards,

Phil Jackson

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the zone's serial number with each change?  Use dig or some other DNS query tool to verify that the SOA record is being updated on your primary authoritative server after you make your changes.  Your first entry should have worked properly.

The other consideration is the TTL setting on the zone file itself.  If you made the DNS change and ran the query too quickly afterward, you could have a negative cache entry causing the local resolver to not go out and try the server again (though a negative cache TTL of 30 hours seems like a lot, I've seen higher times in the wild).  Perhaps try clearing your local resolver cache.

I suspect that the DNS server is just not picking up the change properly though (usually because the serial number on the zone isn't being updated).

Comment: hi thx for the reply. How do you update the serial number? I'm very new to all this ( 3 days of learning ).

Comment: The serial number will be the first part of the data section of the SOA record (usually at the beginning of the zone file).  It must be incremented each time the zone is changed for the server to pick up the change (and the server told to reload the zone data as well, with BIND that would be `rndc reload`).  Usually people will use the format YYYYMMDD## for the serial number on the zone to ensure the number gets updated and allows for 100 changes per day and keeps track of when the zone file was updated.  See: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/soa.html